# How to parse a tab-separated line of text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, delimiter, lexical-analysis, csv

I find Ruby's `each` function a bit confusing. If I have a line of text, an `each` loop will give me every space-delimited word rather than each individual character.

So what's the best way of retrieving sections of the string which are delimited by a tab character. At the moment I have:

```
line.split.each do |word|
...
end
```

but that is not quite correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but if you want to split the lines on tab characters, you can specify that as an argument to split:

```
line.split("\t").each ...
```

or you can specify it as a regular expression:

```
line.split(/\t/).each ...
```

Each basically just iterates through all the items in an array, and split produces an array from a string.

Comment: It's ok for simple cased. But is not *that* simple. There are number of edge cases when the content comes from external source. The newlines, escape sequences, quotes etc are so different between different apps.